How to synchronize asynchronous events in Bloc?
I have the next bloc:
sealed class CameraState extends Equatable {
  const CameraState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class CameraInitial extends CameraState {}

final class CameraReady extends CameraState {
  final CameraController cameraController;

  const CameraReady({required this.cameraController});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [cameraController];
}

final class CameraFailure extends CameraState {
  final String error;

  const CameraFailure({this.error = "CameraFailure"});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
}

final class CameraPermissionDenied extends CameraState {}

sealed class CameraEvent {}

final class CameraStopped extends CameraEvent {}

final class CameraInitialized extends CameraEvent {}

class CameraBloc extends Bloc<CameraEvent, CameraState> {
  final CameraUtils cameraUtils;
  final ResolutionPreset resolutionPreset;
  final CameraLensDirection cameraLensDirection;

  CameraController? _controller;

  CameraBloc({
    required this.cameraUtils,
    this.resolutionPreset = ResolutionPreset.high,
    this.cameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.back,
  }) : super(CameraInitial()) {
    on<CameraInitialized>(_onCameraInitialized);
    on<CameraStopped>(_onCameraStopped);
  }

  Future _onCameraInitialized(
      CameraInitialized event, Emitter<CameraState> emit) async {
    try {
      final isGranted = await cameraUtils.requestPermission();

      if (!isGranted) {
        emit(CameraPermissionDenied());
        return;
      }

      final camera = await cameraUtils.findBestCamera(cameraLensDirection);
      _controller =
      await cameraUtils.createCameraController(camera, resolutionPreset);
      await _controller!.initialize();
      emit(CameraReady(cameraController: _controller!));
    } on CameraException catch (error) {
      _controller?.dispose();
      emit(CameraFailure(error: error.description ?? error.toString()));
    } catch (error) {
      emit(CameraFailure(error: error.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future _onCameraStopped(
      CameraStopped event, Emitter<CameraState> emit) async {
    _controller?.dispose();
    emit(CameraInitial());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    return super.close();
  }
}

The problem is that it contains asynchronous event-to-state mappers, so if I will write a something like below:
bloc.add(CameraInitialized());
bloc.add(CameraStopped());

The state will be changes in order
CameraInitial -> CameraInitial -> CameraReady

not
CameraInitial -> CameraReady -> CameraInitial

It happens due to _onCameraInitialized() execution takes enough long time and contains await points, so execution turn is passed to _onCameraStopped() before _onCameraInitialized() called emit().
Is it possible to synchronize state order in such case? I think about a mutex but it doesn't look as a right way.

Fortunately, Flutter has a special package bloc_concurrency to resolve my problem.

Managing event concurrency can be done with bloc_concurrency and bloc_event_transformers packages.
Alternatively, you can write your own solution by plugging in to the transformer:  argument of each event->method mapping.
